# Excel .xlam file issue

Tags: microsoft-excel, macros

Working with a user who is getting the following error:

[image: Sorry, we couldn't find...]

The file in question is in the right location but for some reason the file path appears to have an illegal character `\` in it. When we click the <kbd>OK</kbd> button Excel closes so we can't edit the path inside of the file. Any ideas?

Comment: maybe this? go about halfway down something about holding the shift key when opening the file...https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16301530/open-a-workbook-from-vba-and-disable-workbook-open-code#:~:text=Here%20another%20way%20to%20open%20with%20out%20the,Workbook.%20For%20VBA%20Work%20with%20Application.EnableEvents%20property%20%28Excel%29